SQL: AVG Before and After Qualified Event Windows
I'm a SQL beginner here & any help will be appreciated.
From a SQL database, table_x, I would like to find qualifying event windows & find x samples average before and after the beginning of the event.
The event: When act_data timeseries data goes above des_data by 20 for 10 consecutive samples, I'm finding the total consecutive samples and average value of speed for that window and output one line of stats for each window (query below works).
However, I'm stuck where I need to find the average value of speed, 30 samples before and 30 samples after the start of the window (ConsecutiveCount CTE), and I get this error:

[GROUPS.SPEED] is not a valid group by expression

Using the avg syntax in ConsecutiveEvents CTE also give me a similar error. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?
Thank you.
Query:
WITH Numbered AS (
    SELECT 
         sn
        ,dt
        ,time
        ,speed
        ,act_data
        ,des_data
        ,(act_data - des_data) AS delta
    FROM table_x
),


ConsecutiveEvents AS (
    SELECT
        sn,
        MIN(time) AS start_time,
        MAX(time) AS end_time,   
        MIN(delta) AS start_delta,
        MAX(delta) AS end_delta,  
        AVG(delta) AS avg_delta,
        COUNT(*) AS sample_count,
        TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, MIN(time), MAX(time)) AS duration_seconds      
    FROM (
        SELECT
            sn,
            time,
            shm,
            speed,
            delta,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sn ORDER BY dt, time) -
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sn, CASE WHEN (delta >= 20)
            THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ORDER BY dt, time) AS group_id
        FROM
            Numbered
    ) AS groups
    
    WHERE
         (delta >= 20)
    GROUP BY
        sn, group_id
    HAVING
        COUNT(*) >= 10
)
--SELECT * FROM ConsecutiveEvents

,ConsecutiveCount as (
    SELECT
        sn
        ,time
        ,shm
        ,speed
        ,act_data
        ,des_data
        ,delta  
        ,AVG(speed) Over(Order By time Rows Between 30 Preceding And 1 Preceding) as prev_30s_spd_avg
        ,AVG(speed) Over(Order By time Rows Between 1 Following And 30 Following) as next_30s_spd_avg
        
    FROM Numbered
)
--SELECT * FROM ConsecutiveCount


,Event_start_stop AS (
SELECT
    sn,   
    start_time,
    end_time,
    start_delta,
    end_delta,
    avg_delta,
    sample_count,
    duration_seconds

FROM
    ConsecutiveEvents
    )

-- SELECT * FROM Event_start_stop

SELECT 
    sn,   
    start_time,
    end_time,
    start_delta,
    end_delta,
    avg_delta,
    sample_count,
    duration_seconds    
    LEAD(start_time) OVER (ORDER BY start_time) as next_time,
    end_time as current_end,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, current_end, next_time) AS int_duration_seconds
FROM Event_start_stop```

